# Write HTML without angle brackets

Tags: html

Is there a way to write HTML without angle brackets? For example, something like this:

```
p Foo
p Bar
```

instead of

```
<p>Foo</p>
<p>Bar</p>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to write markup like that? Essentially, HTML is a markup language which includes angle brackets. To write it in the above format, you'd have to run it through a tool to convert it to HTML and its angle brackets.

Comment: I want to find an easy way to write documents. I don't like Markdown because of it's too automatic. I want to have a full control, like in HTML, but without a lot of `<` `/>` typing. I tried office suits and HTML `white-space: pre-line` but they have their own disadvantages...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without a templating step, there are a few out there, one that sort of looks like what you want is [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/)

Answer (score 1):

[Emmet](http://docs.emmet.io/) provide something approching your request, **it works in the edit phase**, the result is still `html` in the end. [Plugins](http://emmet.io/download/) exist for a variety of editors.
If `vim` is your stuff, there is an effort to provide an [emmet plugin](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim).

example syntax from emmet's docs follows:

you provide:

```
#page>div.logo+ul#navigation>li*5>a{Item $}
```

it can be then *expanded* (transformed) to:

```
<div id="page">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jade` template engine

http://jade-lang.com/

which translates your sample code (and a line added with a class)

```
<p>Foo</p>
<p>Bar</p>
<p class='my-class'>Foo Bar</p>
```

to

```
p Foo
p Bar
p.my-class Foo Bar
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.